# Multiple TextBlocks inside ScrollViewer-Windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scroll, scrollviewer, textblock

We have put a scroll viewer inside a content panel in design page of a databound app. We have to add more number of textblocks inside the scrollviewer which we cannot do by dragging and dropping from the toolbar as the design shows only three textblocks...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You might want to reformat your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the textboxes manually and specify it's margin. You don't need to drag and drop. For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="Content Panel">
     <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox_1" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox_2" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox_3" Margin="10,20,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox_4" Margin="10,30,0,0"/>
```

..and so on.

Margin parameters are Left, Top, Right and Bottom. Keep increasing the top margin to push the control below.